# Multiple file uploading using javascript, jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a website in which i have to upload files to the server. There are many file upload controls out there but none of them has served my purpose, that is I want to upload lets say 1000 files but I want to do it in chunks of 200 files so that server calls are minimum. In the above explained scenario 5 calls would be made to the server. I have look into the Plupload and Dropzone each of them make a separate call to the server i.e. 10 files 10 server calls. Is there any file upload control that serves this purpose or any option in the above mentioned controls that I can make use of?

Comment: Tried https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ ??

Comment: So your looking for Plugin suggestions?

Comment: @MuraliMopuru Yeah i have tried Blueimp but has some issues too..

Answer (score 0):

look into Fineuploader, and perhaps use Amazon S3 as a server-side solution
http://fineuploader.com/